# How to properly change "innodb_buffer_pool_size" value for mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, centos, centos-7

I have following environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
# rpm -qa | grep ^mysql-community-
mysql-community-common-5.5.48-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.5.48-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.5.48-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch
mysql-community-server-5.5.48-2.el7.x86_64
#
```

I need to adjust `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value for `mysql`, however last time when I try to do that, something went south and I end up restoring database from backup( database is ~100G, so ideally I wouldn't want to go that route again.

steps that I took last time:

- stop mysqld
- adjust value of innodb_buffer_pool_size inside of my.cnf
- killed ib_logfile*
- start mysqld

What did I do wrong? What should I do different this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` doesn't need you to nuke ib_logfiles. This could easily be the reason for you had to restore the database (*).

Just stop mysql -> change the settings in my.cnf -> start mysql.

> (*) ib_logfiles are holding recovery data, pages which were not yet
>   checkpoint to the tablespace. If you remove them without making sure
>   you have a clean shutdown you risk losing data and corrupting your
>   database.

Comment: how do I force mysql to save everything from logs into data file(s)?

Comment: You cannot really "force" it but you can change the global variable `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` to 0: `set global innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0`. This will trigger more aggressive checkpointing. This is a common practice to stop mysql "safely" with least amount of downtime.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* delete the iblog files.  You probably have `innodb_fast_shutdown = 1`, which lets you shutdown fast, at the expense of some extra effort on startup.  The files are needed.

1. Change `my.cnf` - add or increase setting for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in the `[mysqld]` section.
2. Stop mysqld
3. Start mysqld

Generally 70% of available RAM is a good value.

Version 5.7.5 implemented dynamic resizing of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  With this version (or later), you can do

1. Change `my.cnf` so that it will be in effect after any restart.
2. `SET GLOBAL...` while the system is running.

No bounce is needed.  The change in size will be gracefully performed in the running system.